# Is the scheduling implemated by a particular OS unique?

Tags: scheduling

I just wanted to ask that on a particular OS ,is the implementation of a scheduling algorithm unique,lets say I am implementing round-robin in my OS ,so will every task within my system get executed on the basis of the time slice decided by the scheduler or only when resources are less then only the threads or processes within the system would  be executed depending on the time slice.

Also ,if round-robin algo is used ,then is there a case that SJF or SRTF may be also implemented,so how does then scheduler decides which algo to use for execution of a particular thread or process.

Comment: Please proof-read and fix question.

Answer (score 0):

By "my OS" are you writing one yourself? What you're really asking "are scheduling algorithm implementations deterministic?"

And the answer to that would be: well it depends on your implementation :-)

Both SJF (shortest-time-first, for those not knowing) and SRTF (shortest-remaining-time- first) can have cases where multiple processes waiting for scheduling have identical weights, and it's down to the scheduler implementation to decide between them.

A naive schedule might always pick the one with the lowest PID, an intelligent scheduler might penalize a process that seems to keep coming back, and somewhere in the middle is the scheduler that tries to do round-robin.

Would it be possible to write a truly deterministic scheduler? Yes, certainly a possibility, but a little bit of randomness in picking the next process (out of a set of random options) to run probably won't hurt, esp. if there are undeclared deadlocks between processes.